# Upgrading from 9 speed to 11 speed on Giant Defy 3

Tags: road-bike, compatibility, upgrades

If I were to upgrade from a complete Shimano Sora R3000 9 speed groupset to a complete Shimano Ultegra 6800 11 speed groupset (excluding hub) on a Giant Defy 3, do I need to get a new hub too or can I just reuse the old hub?

I have never changed the groupset before since I never had the need to change it so I do not know what else do I need other than the groupset itself but since my old groupset is dying on me, I have to change it soon and I though why not upgrade it to an 11 spread instead of simply just replacing the old groupset to the new one

Comment: 9speed to 11speed is NOT an upgrade. Even a 10speed drivetrain, chains and everything wears down very quickly. Imagine how fast a 11 speed setup will wear down and how much it will cost to replace those parts - since they are quite expensive. There are barely any tangible benefits to going to 11speed. Just get the 9speed part replacements.

Comment: @JBeurer Sora to Ultegra very much is an upgrade! And there is no reason why a 10 or 11 speed drivetrain would wear any faster than a 9 speed.

Comment: @JBeurer 11 speed uses newer materials and manufacturing processes. In all honesty I have been getting longer wear life from 11 speed than 10 speed, and I didn’t notice much difference between 9 and 10. I would classify this as a myth.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus the reason is basic physics, 9 speed drivetrain has a wider chain, wider sprocket width, and bigger chain side plates.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus Sora to Ultegra is not an upgrade in any significant way, which can be measured by a Power Meter. Total weight difference between 9spd Sora and 11spd Ultegra (total drivetrain weight) is around ~400 grams. The difference in cassete weight is 50-100g depending on gear ratios. The difference in shifting is negligible. Considering the difference in "Cost of Ownership" and maintenance, calling it an upgrade is very questionable. It certainly doesn't make the bike faster (the difference in speed due to weight difference is so miniscule).

Comment: @JBeurer *internal* width of chain is the same, so are sprockets. I've never heard anyone complain that 10 and 11 speed wear out too fast.

Comment: @JBeur Having ridden Ultegra, 105 and Tiagra I know there is a difference in shifting performance and 400g is not negligible. Shimano is not so stupid as to make their groupsets indistinguishable. I do agree that this upgrade proposal does not make much sense as the rest of the bike is still Sora level.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus Sora and Ultegra groupsets are not indistinguishable. I mean look at it - people buy into this stuff. Ultegra cassettes for example have a different finish (which makes absolutely no difference) and they have more cut-outs an that saves 50-100g (depending on gear ratios, but certainly doesn't make the part more durable). And they have more speeds, i mean think about the SPEEDS. In any real terms, the difference really is very small - especially considering the price and cost of ownership (changing the parts once they wear down on the super thin 10/11speed sprockets and gears)

Comment: Do you have a source on any of this, or are you just making it up as you go? The finish on the chains makes a huge difference. I haven't seen testing on Sora to compare to the 11 speed chains, because they only test reasonably high end components, but have a look at the testing done by Zero Friction Cycling. They found that the Ultegra chain lasted 4.5% longer than the 105 before reaching the same elongation (chain wear and elongation are functionally the same thing). They even found that a Dura Ace chain lasts 30% longer than a 105.

Comment: @JBeurer I'm sorry but you're talking nonsense. 10/11-speed sprockets are not "super-thin": just eyeballing them, I can't see any difference between 10-speed 105 and bottom-of-the-range 7-speed Tourney. (I have nothing to measure them with, but it 10-speed really was "super-thin", there'd be a visual difference.) Of course, the cut-outs on higher-end groupsets don't make them more durable, but I've never heard of anyone breaking a cog: cassettes get replaced when the teeth wear down.

Comment: @Carbonsideup Huge difference - 4.5% longevity (if the zerofriction data is correct, 4.5% might as well be the margin of error). Difference in price 21% (105vsUltegra chain). Totally worth it.
Longevity difference between 105chain and DuraAce is 23%, in price 44%.
11speed drivetrains and their cost of ownership is way past any sort of reasonable point of diminishing returns. For a miniscule marginal increase in "performance", you get a massive increase in cost of ownership and maintenance. That makes it hardly an 'upgrade'. That's the whole point.

Comment: @DavidRicherby durability in this case refers to longevity and wear and tear. How often the parts have to be replaced. And how it impacts cost of ownership vs any sort of reasoanble increase in performance. 10/11-speed sprockets are absolutely super-thin, especially as they wear down (quickly).

Comment: I'm pretty good with bike maintenance to maximise the longevity of components. I can deal with an extra $20 for a Dura Ace chain that I'll be using for the best 12,000 km.

Comment: I also never suggested that it was good value for money or even a worthwhile upgrade for any performance reason. All I did was question a completely inaccurate, unsourced claim.

Comment: @JBeurer Please post some numbers to justify your "super-thin" claim. As I said, I have a ten-speed 105 cassette on a bike parked next to one with 7-speed Tourney. I wouldn't be surprised if the cogs on the 10-speed were slightly thinner but I cannot see any difference without measuring, so "super-thin" seems to be a ridiculous exaggeration.

Answer (score 3):

On road drivetrains the freehub body was made a little wider for 11 speed to accommodate the extra sprocket (34.75mm for 8, 9 and 10 speeds to 36.75mm for 11 speed), so unfortunately the 11 speed cassette cannot be mounted on your hub.

I believe there may be some hacks to get over this, but I cannot provide any information.

Edit: Some 11 speed cassettes will fit on an 10 speed freehub body, specifically larger sizes where the large sprockets can overhang the inboard end of the freehub body, I believe.

You could upgrade to the 10 speed Tiagra group which would still be a substantial bump up in performance and reduction in mass.

It could be said that going to Ultegra is not worth the cost as the rest of the bike is still at Sora level. Also, separate groupsets are relatively expensive, and you have to take into account the cost of installation. Very often it's a better idea to simply buy a new, upgraded bike and sell your old one.

Comment: Aren’t most hubs from the last few years 11-speed compatible? OP might have an 11-speed compatible hub with spacers installed. Only measuring the freehub body can tell for sure.

Comment: @Michael I guess that is a possibility. I would not know how to tell without removing the cassette though. A Sora equipped bike from Giant is likely to have unbranded hubs so it would not be possible to look up the specs of the hub model.

Comment: I do plan to change the entire sora level stuff to ultegra level since I'm changing the groupset. There is a clearance sale on CRC that sells a ultegra groupset that includes 2 shifters, a 11 speed cassette, the chain, front and back derailleurs, front and back brakes and a BBR60 bottom bracket, so if the hub that I'm using isn't compatible with the 11speed cassette, I'll simply have to buy the new hub. That's what I'm thinking but I'm not sure if that's doable or not since I have never done upgrading...

Comment: By 'the rest of the bike' I primarily mean the frame, forks and especially wheels - they will still be entry level.

Comment: Hmm... But is it doable? I want to change the wheel too since is kinda bent

Comment: @Lavenger if you can figure out the freehub width issue, yes. Personally I’d save up and upgrade the whole bike. I’m also curious about why your drivetrain is ‘dying’ R3000 only came out in 2016, modern Shimano products don’t wear out in two years (unless you are a pro, a cycle courier or committed commuter).

Comment: Well by "dying", I meant that the rear derailleur broke apart(two times now) and I only have the front derailleur. The rear cassette is also VERY worn out to the point where I get cuts from washing and maintaining it. Side note: had been hit by cars multiple times from the back even though I was riding safe according to the rules and regulations on the road in Singapore. I also use my bicycle daily and cycle up to 40km±5km every day since its my main commuting vehicle(I had this bicycle for a year and a half now).

Comment: @Lavenger If I were doing that distance I'd want a bike above Sora level for sure. Depending on how bad rear wheel is bent it may be re-pairable.

Comment: It's wobbling around 1-2cm off where the left and right sides are supposed to be I guess, I'm thinking that it's repairable but I have no idea how to do so

Comment: @Lavenger that definitely needs to be addressed by a wheel builder or competent bike repair shop

Comment: Yeah, and if I want to change the hub, the spokes gotta be taken out anyways so there is no point for me to do it by myself, unless I have figured out a way to not change the hub and still fit a 11 speed cassette on it

Comment: @Lavenger Just buy a new wheel

Comment: an 11-34 Ultegra hub will fit on a 10spd cassette

Comment: Edco make a special 11-speed cassette that is designed to fit on 10-speed hubs, but it it expensive, and really only designed for the case when you have a super-posh 10-speed wheelset and don't want to change it when upgrading to 11-speed. However the wheels you have are likely to be pretty basic, and you might consider upgrading those too.

Answer (score 1):

Posting in case anyone else is thinking of doing this: as pointed out already, 9/10s Shimano hubs won't typically take 11s road cassettes, but they will take the 11-34 H800 (Ultegra level) and H700 (105 level) cassette, which will require the medium cage rear derailleurs to work properly. I believe the 9/10s hubs will also take 11s MTB cassettes, and I have heard the smaller ones can also work with medium-cage RDs, but I do question if most people will need them.

These cassettes work because the last cog is cantilevered over the drive-side flange of the hub.

11-34 has a bit of a big jump between sprockets, however, so do take note.

Comment: An 11spd, 11 - 34 cassette has similar jumps to the 9spd, 11 - 27 cassettes of days past, just more of them

Answer (score 0):

Although I typically favor preservation by timely, routine maintenance along with replacement/upgrades that are first, thrifty and second, actually an improvement to the machine.  It's very easy in this business/hobby/passion to be guilty of putting lipstick on a pig.  That is not to imply any sort of poor thinking when one wishes to experience Ultegra instead of old Sora.  Pretty logical, in fact, as the kilometers tick by day after day.  I spent about 25 minutes doing a little web-surfing research as I thought about your situation, and here's what i think:

This [Giant freehub body](https://www.giantbikespares.com/Giant-11-Speed-Loose-Ball-Freehub-Body--FH04KA-501/product_detail/3-41686) is 11 speed, swap-able with your current Defy hub and costs a reasonable 20 pounds. I doubt your rim is trashed and it can be made rideable again.  One consideration may be the degree of wear on the rim's braking surface (though i didn't see it specified, it's likeliest your 2-3 year old Defy 3 has Tektro caliper rim brakes). The Giant SR2 rim has a machined groove around its circumference which is a wear indicator common on rim-brake rims.  The rim's useful life is about done if this groove is worn smooth.  I mention this because, it may be a better value to obtain an entirely new wheel that comes with an 11 speed hub. The repaired, old rim becomes your backup.

There are several listings on Ebay for new (and used) [Ultegra 6800 groupsets](https://www.ebay.com/itm/175mm-Groupset-Shimano-Ultegra-6800-11s-53-39T-Road-Bike-Cycling-brakes-R8000/273447502527?hash=item3faabdc2bf:g:TscAAOSwT69bNbCw).  They're running around $700 with shipping costs considered.  Obtaining just the derailleurs, shifters, chainset, and cassette (that's the minimum of components needed going to 11 speed) will run into the neighborhood of $400.  Neither of these options consider the cost to put these components on and get them in tune.

According to Bicycle Blue Book, a [2016 Giant Defy 3](https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/SearchListingDetail.aspx?id=3059674&make=683&model=61530) is valued somewhere between $2-300.  A high quality groupset represents the greatest chunk of a bike's consumer cost, so I'm not trying to point out the discrepancy in the bike's value "as is" vs. new component cost since I'd be willing to venture that in a cost analysis of a new bike's price, the components comprising the "groupset" represent 2-2.5x the cost of all else that makes up a complete bicycle.   That said, this discrepancy does give one pause when considering the "upgrade."

Finally, note that a [2018 Giant Defy Advanced](https://www.giant-bicycles.com/us/defy-advanced-3-2018) lists for $1685.  This gets you a carbon composite frame, disc brakes, and the 10 speed Shimano Tiagra Groupset, which should be very close in quality and performance to Ultegra 6800.  Interestingly, if it happens to be Tiagra 4700, this model number utilizes the same shift actuation ratio as Shimano's 11 speed groups.  Relevance here is that, presumably, one could do a future upgrade to 11 speed Ultegra a bit more conservatively--piecemeal, if you will--since the 4700 Tiagra shifters would correctly control 11 speed Ultegra derailleurs that you could pair with an 11 speed Ultegra cassette when the Tiagra cassette wears out.  Conventional wisdom states one wears through two cassettes (and at least 2 chains) before the chainwheels need replacing. If you keep to your current bike mileage pace, in a little over 2 years time, you'll be fully Ultegra on a bike whose material and geometry remain in the upper tier of the bike world. In this case, buying new at a well-defined cost(and acquiring the benefits of warranty and one or two free services for the new ride) far outweigh the expenses and risk of this proposed upgrade.

Comment: Hmm. I don't think the Tiagra shifters have the same shift actuation ratio as the 6800s. The relevant metric for shifters would be cable pull, i.e. cable pulled per shift. And in any case, the 6800s have 10 clicks, and the 4700s have 9. So, the OP will need to replace the Tiagra shifters anyway if s/he wants to go to 11s. Now, the *derailleur* actuation ratio may be identical, so the OP could maybe just put 6800 shifters on. https://www.artscyclery.com/science-behind-the-magic/science-behind-the-magic-drivetrain-compatibility/

Comment: @Weiwen Ng  The most expedient evidence i can provide that Tiagra 4700 is engineered along the lines of 11 speed 6800 is [Shimano's Dealer Manual](https://si.shimano.com/pdfs/dm/DM-RD0003-09-ENG.pdf) for road rear derailleurs.  Specifically listed together are the model #'s 9000, 6800, 5800, and 4700.  At any rate, the differing  number of detentes between the shifter models is a key point I've overlooked in my "solution." You're suggestion to go with 6800 shifters likely works since the extra click can be limited out at the derailleur should they choose to keep the 10sp on.  Thanks!